# Could not find DATABASE.SQLPERMISSIONS

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

When building our rather large solution (50 projects) in visual studio 2010 I get the following error. Once I get the error restarting the computer a couple (well once is enough sometimes) of times fixes it for a while and then it reoccurs.

The solution contains both WPF, WCF and database-projects.

**Error message:**
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 10.0\COMMON7\IDE\PROPERTIES\DATABASE.SQLPERMISSIONS'. C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 10.0\COMMON7\IDE\PROPERTIES\DATABASE.SQLPERMISSIONS

The DATABASE.SQLPERMISSIONS-file is located with the other property-files in the database-project where the error always occurs. The build action, copy to output directory and other file properties are set to the same as other, working database-projects.

I've tried

- Deleting the databases from my local SQL-server
- Redeploying
- Clean/Rebuild/Build
- Removing the database-project from the solution build definition
- Restarting the SQL-server/IIS before rebuild
- Deleting output-folders before rebuild

and a whole lot of other things, to no avail.

Does anybody have any suggestions to a semi-suicidal developer? Why would visual studio try to find the permissions-file in program files?

Comment: You may have already seen [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff461429(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Well the problem isn't the permission file content, the problem is visual studio not finding it (since it's looking in the wrong place).

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the project metadata (*.dbmdl) file should solve it.